# What kind of range does one need to sing in an amateur, volunteer choir?

Tags: voice, choir

It's not a professional or collegiate choir; it's all amateurs, unpaid, and all singers and directors/accompanist are volunteers. (There is a brief audition, which I already passed at a sister choir, so that's beside the point of this question for now.)

I have about an octave and a fifth (and a bit more) where I can produce a consistent, pleasant tone, with good pitch control and projection, with no strain. Outside of that octave and a fifth, the tone progressively gets worse and I have less pitch control.

I am working on all this technique-wise, but I'm just curious if an octave and a fifth+ of decent tone production is enough for most amateur volunteer choirs.

Answer (score 3):

Most people's singing range is somewhere between an octave and a half and two octaves. Both extremities can lose tone until worked on. So your octave and a fifth (I'm guessing that's a musical fifth, not 20%!) will be about the same as others in the choir. Very few are blessed with a range of three or more usable octaves, but very useful in choir situations, as they can sing almost any of the parts.

More importantly is *where* that range is. The conductor/director will be aware of where your voice will be in the great scheme of things, and should give you parts that fit with your range. Most are sympathetic, but occasionally you'll find one who gives you parts that are unsingable. They should be the second to know, you being the first! Remember, it's a two-way process. With everyone being volunteers, the atmosphere should be amicable, making all relaxed, thus singing better. If not - find another.